# Is it possible to upload a program from a tablet?

Tags: uploading, ide, android

Is there any easy way to upload a program/sketch from an iPad or Android tablet without adding extra an shield (Bluetooth or Wi-Fi)?

If not, can it be done using shield? Which shield is preferred?

Also what are the IDE options available?

Comment: Related: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/40/what-are-the-other-ides-for-arduino

Comment: "_Which shield is preferred?_" is a little to subjective without any criteria to base it on

Answer (score 6):

I figured out a way to do this without having to port the compiler to iOS. It only works with the arduino Yún, but the Yún can send code to other arduinos with an spi cable.

- Install an SSH app on your device so you can communicate with the arduino
- Using that, install [Ino](http://inotool.org) on your Yún, a command line arduino compiler
- Create a file, put your code in it, then save it
- use [Ino](http://inotool.org) to upload your code!

kind of confusing, but it could work!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Apple doesn't allow apps that implement programming languages. This being said, it is unclear why they would not allow an app that has to do with the Arduino IDE due to the fact that the code doesn't actually run on the Ipad itself.

See [here](http://www.libertypages.com/clarktech/?p=1690) for more Info.

As far as an Android IDE, I have heard that there are a few people working on different IDEs that sends the code to the Arduino over the internet, although they have not been released yet, and the details are still a bit unclear.

Source:
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=61305.0

Comment: Some arduino-eqsue systems already support programming via-Wifi -- [Electric Imp](https://electricimp.com/docs/) comes to mind.

Comment: This comment is a bit old. There are many IDEs in the App Store these days including Python, Rust and Javascript to name a few.

Answer (score 2):

You can always upload to the Arduino via Bluetooth.

1. You must have a bluetooth chip/shield (any should do) and a PC that has bluetooth (or a table that can compile, most likely an Android tablet)
2. You must change the BT baud rate to the same as normal arduino upload, which is 19200 (default BT baud is 9600).
3. Connect the BT to Pin 0 and 1 so act the same as having a USB cord connected
4. Connect a wire to the reset pin to allow remote resetting the arduino to statup the bootloader

   - There must be a delay before
     hitting the reset pin as the bootloader must be active when hitting
     the upload button.
5. Enjoy

For a more detailed description please read: http://ame2.asu.edu/staff/kidane/ArdWilessBtProg.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is only about uploading, this will work with a Yun

- compile your sketches with the IDE on your pc
- for each hex file, copy it to the yun and run `merge-sketch-with-bootloader.lua PATH_TO_HEX_FILE`
- manage to connect to the Yun from your tablet via SSH
- once logged in, run `run-avrdude PATH_TO_HEX_FILE`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any easy way to upload a program/sketch from an iPad or
>   Android tablet without a shield (Bluetooth or Wi-Fi)?

If you don't mind re-writing your program in an interpreted language,
one option is:

- Install an [interpreter on the Arduino](http://playground.arduino.cc/CommonTopics/InterpretedLanguages), perhaps using the standard Arduino IDE running on a standard desktop PC -- like the bootloader, this only needs to be done once.

Then:

- Use your favorite terminal emulator on the tablet
- Somehow link the Arduino and the Android together, and tell the terminal emulator to talk over that link.(*)
- Tell the terminal emulator to send the (more-or-less human-readable plain text) program to the interpreter over the link. (No compiler necessary on the tablet).

(*) There are several different ways to make this link; some of them are mentioned at [How do I write an Arduino sketch and an Android application to talk to each other over a standard USB cable?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/253/how-do-i-write-an-arduino-sketch-and-an-android-application-to-talk-to-each-othe) .

Answer (score 0):

i have been trying out arduinodroid - it's an ide that claims you can upload to your arduino from it. you need an OTG cable (on the go) and to be honest i never actually managed to upload from arduinodroid but others seem to be able to...

my arduino is currently not talking to my computer - a bootloader problem it seems - so i'm getting hold of an AVR ISP MKii - with one of them it is apparently possible to send from terminal ide - an android app, will feedback when and if i get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried android app to programming Arduino Uno via bluetooth, simply by adding [Bluino_Shield](http://www.bluino.com/2015/10/bluino-shield-pre-order.html#.Vkaz9NIrK70) to your Arduino Uno. This link app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluino.bluinoloader

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can upload over BLE with free(mium) iOS app - Apploader

http://www.apploader.info