# How to connect Android phone to Arduino?

Tags: serial, android

Is it possible to connect an Arduino to an Android Phone and use it for input/output?
Are connections possible over USB? Or do I need to have a wifi or Bluetooth shield?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/253/how-do-i-write-an-arduino-sketch-and-an-android-application-to-talk-to-each-othe/254

Comment: @FedericoFissore It's wondering not just USB, but also alternatives like wireless.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson I see. To me it sounded more like a "*can* I use this or do I *have* to use that". Since the answer is "yes" for both, it's not as duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You bet it's possible. I used a pretty cheap bluetooth module that I got from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0093XAV4U), and wrote an app using the information on the official [Android Developers page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) to connect to the Arduino. There are many guides online telling you how to hook up a module to the pins of the duino.

You can probably get a cheaper module if you look on eBay and don't care how long it takes to arrive, and I think there's at least one app on the Play store for controlling an Arduino if you can make it work for your purpose.

USB connections are probably possible, though I haven't done any of that.

Comment: Can you add a guide link and app link? I think "out there un the internet there are things" is not enough

Answer (score 1):

The [Arduino ADK](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardADK) is meant for that. It combines an Arduino Mega with a USB host chip and port. If you don't want to buy a full Arduino, you can buy a [USB host shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9947). Excellent tutorial for it [here](http://labs.arduino.cc/ADK/Index).

What those do is convert high speed USB signals to SPI, which is readable by a microcontroller. Android has libraries known as the Accessory Development Protocol, which can bridge communication from a phone to the USB and then to a microcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

I already had this answer typed up on another question so I thought I'd post it here to help you. I've replaced "tablet" with "phone" for easy reading.

> ### You never mentioned your phone model... or Arduino model
>
> There are some phones designed to work with USB flash drives and
>   printers. This is called OTG (on the go.
>
> **You need:**
>
> - A phone supporting OTG
> - An OTG adapter that fits into your phone's USB slot and is compatible
> - [The Arduino Uno Communicator App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.primavera.arduino.listener)
> - Arduino Uno (or clone) [Note: It says that it works with Atmega16U2 or Atmega8U2 programmed as a USB-to-serial converter so I would assume
>     that that would cover a few boards more than the Uno.)
>
> Another alternitive is to look into
>   [Bluetooth](https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+bluetooth&qscrl=1&tbm=isch&imgil=WyPC4O05Xn4rhM%253A%253Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fencrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com%252Fimages%253Fq%253Dtbn%253AANd9GcSfTtWqIuN9YYdd90OO_tlxsvLUYhV_pl7NfaMhHDzSRq9N6W9rNA%253B1200%253B1200%253B1soQc4CzMzh0MM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fm.dhgate.com%25252Fproduct%25252Fjy-mcu-arduino-bluetooth-wireless-serial%25252F151048482.html&source=iu&usg=__KyMLS4aeubxJnDaMvprgRgADxAs%3D&sa=X&ei=1BUCU635IYmEygGO1oHwCQ&ved=0CGkQ9QEwBg&biw=1280&bih=899)
>   (Note: I just picked a random link but there are hundreds of similar
>   BT adapters)

*[From my answer on a similar question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/272/220)*

Answer (score 1):

You can connect Android and Arduino with usb and use the easy tool App inventor 2 for android

Did you try this new application : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bp.usbbridge.appinvDemo and full version : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bp.usbbridge.appinv

Find Videos about Explications : USB OTG Bridge Serial UART for APP Inventor 2 and ARDUBLOCK on youtube