# Should I use C or C++ for a pure code implementation of Arduino?

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, c

I have an arduino board (SAMD21 microcontroller) which supports either Arduino or CircuitPython programming. I'd like to program in pure C/C++ instead of Arduino, which seems to be possible without too much trouble. But I'm not sure whether to use C or C++. I thought Arduino was based in C++ but I went to look at some of the library files and they were written in C. Since I'm pretty sure they're not interchangeable, can someone help me learn which language I should use to program my board?

Comment: Whichever you are most comfortable in. C is a subset of C++ (or the other way around - C++ is a superset of C).

Comment: You can effectively use either c or c++ in Arduino. There's a few caveats to be aware of, but they both work. You can even inline assembly if you want.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought Arduino was based in C++

There is no language "Arduino" - the Arduino IDE runs a the GNU C++ compiler so "its language" is the language supported by the compiler. It is primarily C++ with a little bit of preprocessing done to your code to help learners get past some of the places they can trip over easily (adding #include statements when it thinks you need them, for instance).

Here is an [answer I wrote to a similar question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/824/313) a few years ago. I think it's relevant to your question.