# Use Arduino Uno to program the on-board Atmega328 in C

Tags: avr, avrdude, avr-gcc

I have an Arduino Uno board.  I have seen how it is possible to program external AVR's through the Arduino Uno board, for instance an ATtiny. But I'm starting with c for atmel µc and I just want to program Atmel328's through the Arduino hardware, and being able to use the arduino pins for outputs etc.

So my question is, can I use the Arduino Uno board together with avrdude and avr-gcc to program the on-board atmel328 in C? And thus being able to use the Arduino pins for output and input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question is not so clear.
But from what I understood you are asking if you can program the Atmega328 with c using low level instruction and by setting manually all the registers in order to use IO ports of atmega. If that's what you're asking I will suggest you to use you're arduino ide to program the Atmega using register names as shown on the official datasheet. Doing so you can start learn the internal parts of the micro and at the same time you can avoid buying an external programmer. But if really want to load you're program or hex file you have to buy an external programmer.
I hope that helped

PS if you are using the arduino ide and writing manually the registers remember not to set incorrectly the configuration registers because that will make you're Atmega useless and you will need to buy an external programmer.

Edit:
For better understanding you can refer to this link.
[Programming arduino in c](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/programming-arduino-uno-in-pure-c/)

Comment: So I can use it as any other programmer together with avrdude and avr-gcc! I don't want to use Arduino IDE, but random C libraries I may have for the ATmega328.  thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Uno is designed to be very simple to program. The only extra hardware you need is a USB cable to connect it to your computer.

If you're completely new to this then the simplest way to start is by following the official "[Getting Started](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/HomePage)" guide. Note that the section on drivers is particularly important.

The guide explains how to use the official [Arduino IDE](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) for programming the microcontroller. It automatically handles compiling and uploading your code via gcc and avrdude. It's technically configured to compile as C++ code, but plain C code should be fine too.

I don't recommend that IDE for long-term use though as it's really only aimed at beginners (it has a number of limitations and other problems). Using the command-line tools directly is certainly possible if you'd prefer that. However, you may also like to consider [alternative IDEs](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/40/what-are-the-other-ides-for-arduino) which have support for Arduino plug-ins.