# Arduino IDE: sketch window has become unresponsive

Tags: arduino-uno, ide

I am very new to all this, but have programmed in other languages using several IDEs. Last night when returning to a coding session, I noticed that the background of the sketch window had gone from white to gray. Then when I tried to continue editing the sketch, I found that I could not make any changes. At all. Clicking anywhere on the screen is futile; the cursor never appears. Text can be highlighted but not copied or pasted. In short, I can’t go on from here at all. 
What have I done?

Comment: You haven't done anything. It's Java. Notoriously bad at staying alive overnight. Kill it.

Comment: As one well-known IT guy would say, _"Have you tried turning it on and off again"_? `:)`

Comment: @duck dodgers: yes I have—multiple times. I’ve also tried using a bigger hammer and waving a dead chicken at it. I’ve not yet gotten to the point that I would kill a goat and examine its entrails, but I am getting close.

Comment: Interesting `:)`. Then could you please possibly post a screenshot of the Arduino IDE here. I have never experienced something like this myself (barring minor glitches which one can get fixed by updating to a [newer version](https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/software)).  Could you please state then the version number of your IDE, what operating system you are using, etc. It would be helpful.

Comment: (see my penultimate comment first please) p.s. you can also try [something other than the Arduino IDE](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/40/what-are-the-other-ides-for-arduino), just for the time, that you try to debug the problem with the "Arduino IDE".